# How to use google maps api to display map and marker at users location

Tags: javascript

I am using the google maps and geolocation api to try display a map thats centered on their location with a marker there, however the map isn't displaying. I initially got it to display but then once I added the getCurrentPosition function it no longer displays. What am I missing and how do I fix it?

```
  var map,latitude,longitude;

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(updateCoords);
  }
  else {
    alert("geolocation not supported by this browser");
  }

  function updateCoords(position){
    latitude: position.coords.latitude,
    longitude:  position.coords.longitude
  }

  function initMap() {
    var options = {
      center = {
        lat:  latitude,
        lng:  longitude
      },
      zoom: 15
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),options);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: map.getCenter(),
        title: "Your Location",
        map: map
      });
      marker.setMap(map);

  };
```

Comment: You have some JS errors, both in your Options object and your updateCoords function

Comment: @TtotheJ Hi do you have any suggestions for the comments in the provided answer?

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my answer so that the marker will display. Because getCurrentPosition is asyncronous your original latitude and longitude values were only set after the map tried to initiate.

This code only adds the marker to the map after the location is found.

```js
var map,latitude,longitude;

if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(updateCoords);
}
else {
  alert("geolocation not supported by this browser");
}

function updateCoords(position){

  var center = {
    lat: position.coords.latitude,
    lng: position.coords.longitude
  }

   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: center,
      title: "Your Location",
      map: map
    });
    marker.setMap(map);
    
    map.setCenter(center);
}

function initMap() {
  // all fields inside a json object use : instead of =
  var options = {
    center: {
      lat: 0,
      lng: 0
    },
    zoom: 15
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),options);
};
```

Comment: Hi, I have made the changes you made and it seems to create the map object but it is greyed out. I can tell the maps there as well since hovering over gives the option to move the map about.

Comment: Ok so after looking in the console log I found it produces this error: InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number

Comment: I've tried a solution from this website which suggests using parseFloat, however the map is still grey

Comment: Ok so the updateCoords does update the latitude and longitude variables however they don't update the lat and lng inside options

Comment: You mentioned the map being grey. Do you have the proper API keys set up with Google?

Comment: yes, the map properly works if i hard code some values into options

Comment: Ok I decided to make a work around of it, rather than getting the users location at the start and trying to display it straight away, I simply show the UK then when the user accepts the prompt for geolocation I move to there